# KendoDatePicker не работает событие change при вводе с клавиатуры

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, kendo

Проект на ASP.NET 4 MVC. На форме есть `<input id="birthday" name="birthday" />`, с помощью следующего скрипта пытаюсь сделать проверку на правильный ввод даты.

```
$("#birthday").kendoDatePicker({ format: "dd.MM.yyyy", 
min: new Date(1900, 0, 1),
max: new Date(),
change: onBDayOwnerChange });
```

И соответственно функция

```
function onBDayOwnerChange(e) {
    var dt = e.sender;
    var value = dt.value();

    debugger;

    if (value === null) {
        value = kendo.parseDate(dt.element.val(), dt.options.parseFormats);
    }

    if (value < dt.min()) {
        dt.value(dt.min());
    } else if (value > dt.max()) {
        dt.value(dt.max());
    }
}
```

Проблема в том что событие change срабатывает если пользователь меняет значение с помощью "календаря" datePiker, но не работает года меняет значение с клавиатуры.

Comment: После ввода данных нажмите enter. Должно вывести что нибудь, например "Sun Dec 10 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (Центральная Азия (зима))"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать  вот так для теста, будет ли что нибудь выводить.

Событие **change** происходит по окончании изменения значения элемента формы, когда это изменение зафиксировано. Например после потери фокуса, нажатия ENTER.

```
<input id="birthday" />

<script>
$("#birthday").kendoDatePicker({
    change: function() {
        var value = this.value();
        console.log(value); 
    }
});
</script>
```

Так же попробуйте такой вариант:

```
var datePicker =  $("#birthday").data("kendoDatePicker");
    datePicker.value("01/01/20017");
    datePicker.trigger("change");
```

Код:

```
$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({ 
  format: "dd.MM.yyyy", 
  min: new Date(10, 0, 2017),
  max: new Date(),
  change: onBDayOwnerChange //Срабатывает
});

$("#datepicker").on("change", function(){
   onBDayOwnerChange(); //Срабатывает
});

function onBDayOwnerChange(e) {
  alert("Работает"); 
}
```

Пример **keypress**:

```
$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({ 
  format: "dd.MM.yyyy", 
  min: new Date(10, 0, 2017),
  max: new Date(),
  change: onBDayOwnerChange
});

$("#datepicker").on("keypress", function(){
   var datePicker =  $(this).data("kendoDatePicker");
   datePicker.trigger("change"); 
});

function onBDayOwnerChange(e) {
  alert("Работает");
}
```

Comment: В первом варианте при вводе с клавиатуры не работает событие, при изменении с помощью календаря выводит дату в лог.

Comment: первый раз выводит null, потом даже при изменении значения - ничего. После того как поменяю с помощью календаря и затем введу значение с клавиатуры - опять один раз null

Comment: второй вариант если добавить его в  change: function() {} не работает. Мне необходимо чтобы когда пользователь что то ввел неверно с клавиатуры, значение менялось на минимальное, как в скрипте. Но как его вызвать я не понимаю

Comment: Неверный формат даты, дата не попадающая в диапазон, если вы посмотрите скрипт, там эти ситуации обрабатываются, проблема в том что не работает событие

Comment: Да, буду смотреть, самое интересное что иногда срабатывает, а можете объяснить в чем смысл на change вешать триггер change? Никак не могу понять

Comment: @e1s это пример, вы можете сделать просто   onBDayOwnerChange();

Comment: @e1s Обновил ответ, думаю так будет понятнее